# ReactCSSTransitionGroup - how to override componentWillLeave(callback)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to access the `componentWillMount` hook in order to fade out a canvas element that is not a child of the transitioning `<Home>` component. (Animation of `<Home>` itself works as expected.)

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="screenTrans" transitionEnterTimeout={200} transitionLeaveTimeout={3000}>
    <Home key={'home'} />
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Home.js:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentWillLeave( callback ) {
        console.log( "am i getting called?" ) // no!
        this.fadeOutCanvas();
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Quite late answer but I'm now facing the same problem.

The thing is that you're using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` which does NOT call the callbacks like `ReactTransitionGroup` (different component). The problem is that you would need a component that does both (sets css AND calls your callback)

From the docs:

> When using ReactCSSTransitionGroup, there's no way for your components to be notified when a transition has ended or to perform any more complex logic around animation. If you want more fine-grained control, you can use the lower-level ReactTransitionGroup API which provides the hooks you need to do custom transitions.

Checked around and I couldn't find anything, so I'll write my own component and hopefully open source it!